Filtering a minimum value from the first date in a month
I'm working on a model that has two tables: A calendar table called 'DATE' and a transactions table called 'GL Master'. In the GL Master table, there's a column called 'Date' which records all the movements made in two columns, one is called 'Amount' and the other one is 'Balance', the first one records all the movements made in a specific date and the other one holds the total of all movements in a month. I want to retreive the initial balance, which is in this balance column at the very begining of any month. sometimes there are more values registered at the first date of any month, so I want to include the minimum balance amount for every first date of the month from my table. There's another column that I'm using to filter my GL Master table, which is called 'Account Name'. I'm attaching a snapshot of the table I'm working with, so you can understand me better.
GL Master Table, and the columns I'm working with
I used this formula to get a similar result, and it worked with another account called 'Assets', I'm working with 'Liabilities' but I can't get the number I want because there are several amounts in the first date of some accounts.
Assets Balance 1st Value = 
VAR first_date = MIN('GL Master'[Date])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        [Master Balance TT],
        'GL Master'[Category 2] = "Assets",
        'GL Master'[Date] = first_date
    )


Does your date table have a [First of Month] Field? Also can you please post the code for [Master Balance TT] ?

what‘s the expected output based on the sample data you provided?

I found a solution to my problem, but I didn't use any DAX, instead, I had to create an extra column from Power Query. The column contained a label "Initial balance" for every "Account name", I got these labels from an Excel file. I only mapped this new label column to match the date column in my GLMASTER table. from there, it was so much easier to calculate everything.
